# Update two table fields, each with the other value

Tags: mysql, sql, string, join, sql-update

Maybe someone can help me with this.

I have a MYSQL table with first name and last name.
Some rows were added with last name in the first name column and first name in the last name column.

How can I flip these. I tried a simple update `SET firstname = lastname, lastname = firstname` but that doesn't work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+-----------+----------+
| firstname | lastname |
+-----------+----------+
| Potter    | Harry    |
+-----------+----------+

mysql> update mytable 
  set lastname = (@temp := lastname), -- no-op, but sets a variable as a side effect
      lastname = firstname, 
      firstname = @temp;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mytable;
+-----------+----------+
| firstname | lastname |
+-----------+----------+
| Harry     | Potter   |
+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do that in a simple `update`  statement in MySQL, because consecutive assignments in the `set` clause are not independent. This does not work:

```
update mytable set first_name = last_name, last_name = first_name
```

When the second assignment is executed, `first_name` is set to `last_name` already. Doing so would hence set both columns to `last_name`.

This is not standard SQL, but that's how MySQL does it. One option uses a self-join. Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`:

```
update mytable t
inner join mytable t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.first_name = t1.last_name, t.last_name = t1.first_name
```